# Xcode 4.3.1: Unable to open documents of type iPad XIB

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, interface-builder

I have just upgraded to Xcode 4.3.1 and SDK 5.1. My project uses storyboard but has one nib/xib file. After the upgrade the compile fails with:

```
/* com.apple.ibtool.errors */
/Users/jhn/Udvikling/Projekter/rmtelemedicin/RMTeleMedicin/RMTeleMedicin/MenuViewController.xib: error: Interface Builder is unable to open documents of type iPad XIB.
    Recovery Suggestion: Ensure the plugin for the iPad XIB document type, from the corresponding SDK, is installed.
```

Any one seeing the same problem?Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should ask this question on Apple's development forums: if this is a genuine problem, you should see numerous messages by now, perhaps even with explanations on how to fix it.

Comment: And submit a bug report.

Comment: I have this problem too, and I didn't find any solution on Apple Development forum.

Comment: Someone has asked on the forums with no answer yet https://devforums.apple.com/thread/144178

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I figured it out!

Go to your project settings, and delete the line that says Interface Builder Plugin search path or something similar.

the exact line in project.pbxproj is:
`IBC_PLUGIN_SEARCH_PATHS = "${PROJECT_DIR}/**";`

That's it.

Comment: Yep, that fixed it. Not really sure whether this "fix" breaks something else though -- but I suppose will not since IB plugins have been killed by Xcode 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. I just created a new project and copied all the source/xib/resources files to the new project. Hope it helps someone

Answer (score 0):

**To fix this:**

1. Press Command-1 to go to the project tree
2. Select your project
3. The in the right panel select your project, and then click on "Build Settings"
4. In search field just below the "Build Settings" enter: "Overriding Plug-In"
5. Now, the only visible setting left should say "Overriding Plug-In and Framework Directory"
6. Double-click the value and remove all entries using "-" button
7. Click somewhere else so settings are saved

That should fix it